# html.raw is not rendering

Tags: c#, html, razor

I'm trying to modify the background color of a table row using the code below. However, I'm getting a parser error because the closing tr tag doesn't have a matching opening tr. I tried using @: instead of @Html.Raw(...), but I get the same error. If I type the tr tag outside of the conditional block, it renders a single tag and the table loads fine (just without alternating background colors).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        i++;
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            @Html.Raw("<tr>");
        }
        else{
            @Html.Raw("<tr style=\"background-color: #c9c9c9\">");
        }

        <td>@i.ToString()</td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: There's no need to Raw in this case, just print the HTML

Comment: @Html.Raw(i%2==0 ? "<tr>" : "")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        string backColor;
        i++;
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            backColor = "whatever this color should be";
        }
        else {
            backColor = "#c9c9c9";
        }
    <tr style="background-color: @backColor">
        <td>@i.ToString()</td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `@Html.Raw` on those places.

Simply leave the tags as is  `<tr>`

**Update... adding your code.**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        i++;
        if (i % 2 == 0){

            <tr>
        }
        else{
          <tr style='background-color: #c9c9c9'>
        }

        <td>@i.ToString()</td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Removing Html.Raw resulted in a parser error for a missing closing bracket. I assume this has to do with the conditional inside the foreach loop. I wasn't able to get this to work, but @craig-w's solution did the trick. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Ryan It should have worked. i'm sure there was a typo or something. I've updated my answer with your code excluding the `Html.Raw`. Just in case you still need it.